# No "using" reference in asp.net generated code

Tags: asp.net, code-generation

When I looked at the generated code of an aspx page, one thing struck me. Every class reference is printed every time instead of applying the "using" method at the top of the code file.
Is there a reason for doing this?
If there's no difference in the two methods then why not use "using" for simplicity?

```
System.Data.DataSet theSet = new DataSet();
```

vs

```
using System.Data;  
DataSet theSet = new DataSet();
```

Comment: +1, I've wondered about this myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because for generated code, simplicity of *reading* is not a priority.

Simplicity of *writing* is an issue, however: If types are always specified with their fully qualified name, the likelihood of a name conflict decreases. Imagine that you have two libraries that provide TextBox controls, and you add both of them to your web form.

```
// no problem
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox myDefaultTextBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
CustomLibrary.TextBox theOtherTextBox = new CustomLibrary.TextBox();
```

as compared to

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using CustomLibrary;  

// won't compile, would need special treatment by the code generator
TextBox myDefaultTextBox = new TextBox();
TextBox theOtherTextBox = new TextBox();
```

Comment: +1 but I think I would say simplicity of reading was not a priority rather than not an issue.  There are times where you want to read the generated code and it would be appreciated if it was slightly cleaner, but it's not a big deal so the time required wouldn't be worth it for the minor benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to help avoid type ambiguities.

Update: More elegantly described by Heinzi.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to fully qualify the type name like that unless there is some kind of coding standard you are following for clarity.